# How to politely ask someone to hurry up because of lack of time?

Tags: communication, deadlines

There is a professor who is willing to allot an open position in the lab but he's just delaying about it. He just won't tell me what project is he going to assign to me. He told me he wants to talk to other people and see if their projects are more relevant to me. I want to politely ask him to speed up the process. How do I do that?

Comment: ELU doesn't really do this sort of etiquette thing as it's not the nuts and bolts of grammar. But I think it has appeared in the past on Workplace.

Comment: @AndrewLeach could you post the link here? How do I search for it. I am sorry, I am new to this site.

Comment: Possibly something like ["How long to wait..."](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47544/how-long-to-wait-for-a-written-job-offer-to-arrive). Note that, as RegDwight commented on ELU, no Stack Exchange site does ghost-writing -- not even Writers.

Comment: Unless you have a very urgent reason, leave it. "He told me he wants to talk to other people and see if their projects are more relevant to me" Why do you think your arguments are more important than his? And it helps if you [edit] your question and put in some time indications - how long has this been going on?

Comment: I agree, I think we need more information on why you would like him to hurry up. If you have other lab's offering you a position, then I would consider it a duplicate of [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111/how-do-i-coordinate-the-process-of-pursuing-multiple-job-opportunities-at-the-sa)

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, i saw that. I am just asking for a proper way of telling something, I know what I have to say, just not how to say it politely.

This thing has been going on for around 20 days. I went to an intern there last year and his cabin is just next to other supervisors and he generally takes lunch with them. I am just unsure if he has changed his mind regarding my recruitment. I don't want to lose other possible options. I am currently at home wasting time unproductively. Should I use "with all due respect" before my thoughts? It sounds as if I am counter-arguing him in some way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Professors are notorious for lacking a sense of urgency in these types of areas of: logistics, operations, bureaucracy, red tape, paperwork, etc. Rarely do they understand things from a business perspective. Some are better than others, but they're not common. Also, believe it or not, they are very busy people. They do more than just teach a few classes.

Take these two factors into consideration and realize that you need to prompt them more frequently. Just ask if they've been able to look into your request. If they say, "I'll look into it next week." don't wait for next week to finish. Ask in the middle of the week. Again, they need prompting and if you're not doing it, they'll just attend to some other task that they may feel is more pressing.

At some point, the professor could get irritated by your continuous prompting, but you really have no choice if you want to get this assignment completed. You can always back off on the level of prompting. Do not say things like, "You said you would do it last week." or try to hold them to some other verbal commitment. You're not their boss and you're just one of a dozen requests they are trying to manage. Just indicate you want to remind them. Keep it simple, nice, non-threatening or sounding like you're entitled to any kind of quick action.