# 2 months and counting

Tags: hiring

[image]

I started with the process of interview in company x, cleared 8 rounds of interviews successfully and cleared the background check.

Verbally, several times, they have told me things like, your offer letter is ready, I will send you your offer letter, please bear with me, but I haven't receive any offer letter.

It's been 2 months and now they reject my calls and do not respond to my email or whatsapp messages.

- Are they still working on it?
- What could be the reason for delay?
- Is this professional?
- Should I keep waiting?

Last contact with HR was 10 days ago.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest chasing down other opportunities, this one appears to be done for.

Comment: I dont understand that why have they kept me in the dark,they told me several times about the offer letter

Comment: My guess would be that a change in the company means that they are no longer able to offer you the job, but the person responsible is trying to avoid you so that they do not have to admit that.

Comment: See also [How long to wait for a written job offer to arrive?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47544/how-long-to-wait-for-a-written-job-offer-to-arrive)

Answer (score 4):

> Are they still working on it?

I guess not. They are outright ignoring you the way you pose your story.

> What could be the reason for delay?

There could be a definite reason ofcourse. But this seems a lot like they can't be bothered with informing people they didn't make the cut.

> Is this professional?

No.

> Should I keep waiting?

I surely hope you're not still waiting.

Comment: The hiring manager called me, he asked me to be patient, and wait for a few more days, his tone was not too convincing.I dont understand whats on the way.