# Received Offer, went through successful salary negotiation then silent for 1 month

Tags: new-job, human-resources, germany

I am needing some advice on this situation.

I have applied for a job that will require relocation to a foreign country in Europe and the hiring manager I am dealing with seems to be very slow and generally unresponsive to email, so I am in a bit of a difficult situation with trying to make plans for my future.

> The timeline of the events are listed below for reference:
>
> 7th of March - Applied for position
>
> 29th of May  - Interview request
>
> 14th of June - 1st interview
>
> 27th of June - 2nd interview
>
> 13th of July - Job offer
>
> 14th of August - Salary negotiation concludes

It is now the middle of September and I have yet to actually receive a formal job offer.

Should I be feeling frustrated right now, or should I just relax and go with the slow-flow of this company? I am eager to leave my current position, but without a formal offer it is a calculated risk as to whether I give notice already.

I did have someone more senior add me on Linkedin welcoming me to the company, but I feel like I might be stepping on some toes by side-stepping my hiring manager and communicating directly with them to try and find out what is going on.

For some background they are a multi-national company in Germany in the medical industry.

Comment: [How long to wait for a written job offer to arrive?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/47544)

Comment: Unfortunately, large companies have slow processes, and need a thousand levels of approval, so it could be 'normal'.

Comment: That's slow. It happens. Some companies are going to hire you for yesterday, others within one year. There is no rule.

Answer (score 2):

Nobody gonna hate you for asking this linkedin person about the job - you *want* the job, right? Push for it. Aggressively push them. Politely.

I've never heard of a company saying "well, Sam wants to work here, that's a mark against her.